Cannot access subfolders in Google Drive
I log on to my online accounts and Google Drive main folder appears. Files in the main folder are there and I can see the names of the subfolders. But I cannot access them. There are no icons for subfolders, only names. Is there anything I can do? Thanks in advance.
My Ubuntu version: 24.04 LTS
